# Converting for loop to while loop in Java

Tags: java

I need to convert this for loop into a while loop so I can avoid using a break.

```
double[] array = new double[100];

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 

for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.print("Sample " + (index+1) + ": ");
        double x = scan.nextDouble();
        count++;
        if (x < 0) 
        {
            count--;
            break;
        }
        array[index] = x; 
    }
```

This is what I came up with but I'm getting a different output:

```
int index = 0;

double x = 0; 

while (index < array.length && x >= 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Sample " + (index+1) + ": ");
        x = scan.nextDouble();
        count++;
        if (x < 0) 
        {
            count--;
        }
        array[index] = x;
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: Excuse me, but why in God's name would you 1) want to use while instead of for, and 2) avoid break? Usually those two intentions make your code a lot harder to read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution gives the same output as the for loop:

```
while (index < array.length && x >= 0)
{
    System.out.print("Sample " + (index+1) + ": ");
    x = scan.nextDouble();
    count++;
    if (x < 0) 
    {
        count--;
    }
    else
    {
        array[index] = x;
        index++;
    }
}
```

**EXPLANATION:**

On the for loop you use the break statement so nothing happens after the program hits the break. So `array[index] = x;` didn't get executed.

On the while loop since there's no break, the loop continues, so the statements `array[index] = x;` and `index++;` got executed.

That's why you got different results. If you don't want the statements

```
array[index] = x;
index++;
```

To be executed you can simply make your if statement a if/else statement as above.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (x < 0) 
{
    count--;
}
array[index] = x;
index++;
```

to something like

```
if (x < 0) 
{
    count--;
} 
else 
{
    array[index] = x;
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid break, changing the for loop into a while loop doesn't help in any way.

How about this solution:

```
boolean exitLoop = false;
for (int index = 0; index < array.length && !exitLoop; index++)
    {
        System.out.print("Sample " + (index+1) + ": ");
        double x = scan.nextDouble();
        count++;
        if (x < 0) 
        {
            count--;
            exitLoop = true;
        }
        else {
            array[index] = x;
        }
    }
```